# How would I draw a line to connect the dots in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

I've been trying to use painter to draw the line between to dots but I have two problems that I need to resolve.

1. I need to know which dots are connected to each other
2. I need the line to snap into the dot when it is close to it

You can refer to the design below

[image]

Could Draggable plugin do the trick here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find the solution for the first point:

> I need to know which dots are connected to each other

I create 4 keys

```
GlobalKey _keyTopLeft = GlobalKey();
GlobalKey _keyBottomLeft = GlobalKey();
GlobalKey _keyTopRight = GlobalKey();
GlobalKey _keyBottomRight = GlobalKey();
```

I then added each key to the widget I want to track:

```
_letterWidget(
    key: _keyTopLeft,
)
_letterWidget(
    key: _keyBottomLeft,
)
_letterWidget(
    key: _keyTopRight,
)
_letterWidget(
    key: _keyBottomRight,
)
```

I created a list tracking which dots the finger has touched:

```
List<bool> ongoingSequence = List.filled(4, false);
```

Then I did the logic on the GetureDetector widget

```
GestureDetector(
      onPanDown: (DragDownDetails details) {
        ongoingSequence = List.filled(4, false);
        getDragDownPosition(details);
      },
      onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
        getDragUpdatePosition(details);
        var result = BoxHitTestResult();
        RenderBox renderBoxTopLeft =
            _keyTopLeft.currentContext.findRenderObject();
        RenderBox renderBoxBottomLeft =
            _keyBottomLeft.currentContext.findRenderObject();
        RenderBox renderBoxTopRight =
            _keyTopRight.currentContext.findRenderObject();
        RenderBox renderBoxBottomRight =
            _keyBottomRight.currentContext.findRenderObject();
        if (renderBoxTopLeft.hitTest(result,
            position: details.localPosition)) {
          ongoingSequence[0] = true;
        } else if (renderBoxBottomLeft.hitTest(result,
            position: details.localPosition)) {
          ongoingSequence[1] = true;
        } else if (renderBoxTopRight.hitTest(result,
            position: details.localPosition)) {
          ongoingSequence[2] = true;
        } else if (renderBoxBottomRight.hitTest(result,
            position: details.localPosition)) {
          ongoingSequence[3] = true;
        }
      },
```

Then we can print the ongoingSequence list for the results:

```
print("top-left ${ongoingSequence[0]}");
print("bottom-left ${ongoingSequence[1]}");
print("top-right ${ongoingSequence[2]}");
print("bottom-right ${ongoingSequence[3]}");
```